# Resizing logo on scroll

Tags: css, scroll

Hi I have a script which works fine for resizing a logo on scroll down and back again, but i dont want it to do it when the screen size is less than 600px how do i alter to achieve this any help greatly appreciated.

```
// When the user scrolls down 50px from the top of the document, resize the header's font size
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
    document.getElementById("header-logo").style.width = "180px";
 } 
   else {
   document.getElementById("header-logo").style.width = "215px";
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
if (screen.width > 600px){
    //your code
}
```

Comment: tried but didnt work
if (screen.width > 600px){
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
    document.getElementById("header-logo").style.width = "180px";
  } 
 else {
    document.getElementById("header-logo").style.width = "215px";
  }
}
}

Comment: try without px.and add `window` before screen. so... `window.screen.width > 600`

Comment: also, i think it you need to take scrollbar into account you could use window.screen.availWidth

Answer (score 0):

You can use `media queries` to achieve this

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #header-logo {
    width: 180px !important;//!important use to override inner html styles 
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah that works but when the window is scrolled back up it goes back to being 215px

Comment: In desktop or mobile.... if thats happen then try to add class on scroll using js and then style it .. that will definitely do that

Answer (score 0):

with a bit of luck and using some of DoomBots code got it to work with the below
    // When the user scrolls down 50px from the top of the document, resize the header's font size
    window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

```
function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50 || 
screen.width < 600) {
    document.getElementById("header-logo").style.width = "180px";
  } 
    else {
       if (screen.width > 600){
       document.getElementById("header-logo").style.width = "215px";
 }
 }
```

}